# Problem with coordinates not being calculated in decimal degrees

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I have a qGIS question regarding the calculation of x and y coordinates and showing the results in decimal degrees.  Initially I was using the 3.2 version, but went back to the 2.18.13 version because the newer version was really off for the coordinates (it would return 40.7768, -65.7466 when hovering over a point that was closer to 38.78, -76.87, for example).  The 2.18.13 version of qGIS seems to be giving the right coordinates when hovering over a point, but when calculating them into a new field, the results returned aren't in decimal degrees (i.e. 1343104.31085 for x and 531546.19274 for y).  The layer is set to a CRS of NAD83 HARN (EPSG:4269 (OTF)). Is there a conversion factor that should be used?  I have tried saving the dataset as a shp file (it was already), adding fields and calculating using $x and $y, and I have also used the toolbox to add geometry, and receive the same results - not in decimal degrees.  Any advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert UTM coordinates into Decimal Degree coordinates?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91119/how-to-convert-utm-coordinates-into-decimal-degree-coordinates)

Comment: The layer looks like it's using EPSG:26785, **NAD27** State Plane Maryland (in US survey feet). @lambertj not a duplicate of the UTM question.

Comment: I tried EPSG:26985, NAD83 State Plane Maryland to do the same calculations, but was unsuccessful, however, it may have been a permissions issue, since when I saved the shapefile again to another name and set the CRS to NAD83 HARN (EPSG:4269 (OTF), and redid adding the fields and calculations, it worked and returned the coordinates in decimal degrees.  Thanks

Comment: Good to hear that worked for you, Robin. You should post your solution as an answer and accept it. May help others down the line.

Answer (score 1):

It may have been a permissions issue, since when I saved the shapefile again to another name and set the CRS to NAD83 HARN (EPSG:4269 (OTF)), and redid adding the fields and calculations, it worked and returned the coordinates in decimal degrees.